# React Native <TextInput> displaying the wrong value

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-textinput

I'm trying to do a 6 digits verification code form (I know there is actually a package to do but I want it differently).

So I've done it like so:

```js
const RegisterStep2 = (props) => {
  const [digits, setDigits] = useState([]);
  const textInputRefs = [];

  const isNumeric = (str) => {
    if (typeof str == 'number') return true;
    if (typeof str != 'string') return false;
    return !isNaN(str) && !isNaN(parseFloat(str));
  };

handleForm = (index, value) => {
    let digitsArray = digits;
    let trueIndex = index;
    for (let i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (!isNumeric(digits[i])) {
        trueIndex = i;
      }
    }
    textInputRefs[trueIndex].focus();
    index = trueIndex;

    if (!isNumeric(digits[index])) {
      if (value.key == 'Backspace' && textInputRefs[index - 1] != undefined) {
        textInputRefs[index - 1].focus();
      }
      if (isNumeric(value.key)) {
        digitsArray[index] = value.key;
      } else {
      }
    } else {
      if (value.key == 'Backspace') {
        digitsArray[index] = '';
      } else if (isNumeric(value.key)) {
        digitsArray[index] = value.key;
      }
    }
    setDigits(digitsArray);
    if (isNumeric(digits[index]) && textInputRefs[index + 1]) {
      textInputRefs[index + 1].focus();
    } else if(index == textInputRefs.length) {
      submitForm();
    }

return (
  ...
  <TextInput
    ref={(input) => {
      textInputRefs[1] = input;
    }}
    style={style.formDigit}
    keyboardType={'numeric'}
    maxLength={1}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    value={digits[1]}
    onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
      handleForm(1, nativeEvent);
    }}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
  />
  ... //The same input x3 times with corresponding index
  <TextInput
    ref={(input) => {
      textInputRefs[5] = input;
    }}
    style={style.formDigit}
    keyboardType={'numeric'}
    maxLength={1}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    value={digits[5]}
    onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
      handleForm(5, nativeEvent);
    }}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
  />
  ...
);
```

Everything is working pretty well but the value of the input doesn't update in the way I want, when the user presses a key that is not handled by the handleForm (NaN), the input doesn't display what it that should **(`digits[index]`)** but it displays the pressed key(not the value it is bind to).

[digits value result as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Wwx.png)

[digits render not as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9lpX.png)

[digits render as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIaIg.png)

Same for when the user is writing in a textInput that is not the first empty one, the input that should be written should be the first empty one:

[digits value as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ0YC.png)

[digits render not as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4UyD.png)

[digits render as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrMzT.png)

So I wonder why the value that is displayed isn't the real state value, did I broke something, why the pipe between the state and the input seems broken.
Even when the state gets updated (so the view is re-rendered), the input doesn't display his true value.